# Number with n digits divisible by given number

Tags: c++, modulo

i need to find ANY number >0 with n digits(<=10) divisible by a number m (<=10 also).

This is what i tried:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, t, k, r=1;
    cin>>n>>t;
    k=n;
    while(k--)
        r*=10;  // i am making 10^n
    r/=10;      // a 0 was in plus
```

Now I search from 10^n to 10^n + 10 a number that is divisible by t, knowing that I have t<=10, i should have a number divisible by it.

```
    for(int i=r; i<=r+10; ++i)
    if(i%t==0){
            cout<<i;
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I only got this example:

```
3 2
```

And the answer is 712 but i can output any.

For an input my code is wrong, i don't know why.

Comment: Whether or not it is homework is not relevant; what's important is the amount of effort put into the question. In this case, that appears to be zero.

Comment: I tried something but it's wrong, would you tell me how to do it?

Comment: If you show us what you tried and tell us how it's wrong, then yes; that's what this site is for. If you don't do either of those things, however, we will not write code for you.

Comment: To enhance @R_Kapp 's comment, provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Done, now please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: As I recall, a number N is divisble by Q if (N % Q) == 0.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, giving any n, I need to find any number with n digits divisible by a given m.

Comment: @Mas: You're halfway there with the question; now you need to tell us what the output of the code is and why it's wrong.

Comment: Have you considered a Big Number library?  What is the maximum number of digits?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i wrote clearly, N<=10

Comment: @Mas: When I use your code [here](http://ideone.com/G0FSi4), I get the output 100, which is what I would expect the program as written to do.

Comment: @Mas I'd recommend to step through with the debugger, and inspect variable values.

Comment: @R_Kapp yup but somehow for 1 test i'm getting wrong answer :)

Comment: Which test? The one you've posted (`3 2`) works as it should.

Comment: @R_Kapp that's the problem, i can't see it

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know how many N digit numbers can be divided by M then this can be accomplished fairly easily using a formula.  Lets say we want to know all 5 digit numbers that are divisible by 17.  What we do is find the smallest 5 digit number that can be divided by 17.  so if we do

```
10000 % 17
```

We get `4` so when we do

```
10000 - 4 + 17
```

we get 10013 which is the first 5 digit number that can be divided by 17.  Now we need to know how many mutiples of 17 are in the range of [10013, 99999].  We need to find the largest 5 digit integer and we can get that with simple integer division and multiplcation

```
99999 / 17 * 17 = 99994
```

And to get the number of multiples we take

```
(max   - min  ) / 17
(99994 - 10013) / 17
    89981       / 17 = 5293
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Is this what you need ?

First number n, is the number of digits.
Second number m, is the divider.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int m, n;
bool searchDivisibleNumbers(int n, int m);

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;

    while (searchDivisibleNumbers(n,m))

    return 0;
}

bool searchDivisibleNumbers(int n, int m)
{
    int digits = pow(10, n-1); //huge number of n digits

    while (digits != 0){

        if (digits % m == 0){
            cout << digits << " is divisible by " << m << endl;
        }
        digits--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Input: n=3 (3 digits) m=17
Output:

```
    3 17
85 is divisible by 17
68 is divisible by 17
51 is divisible by 17
34 is divisible by 17
17 is divisible by 17
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: No, i need to find any number with N digits divisible by a random given number!

Comment: You cant generate a random number ? My solution luck the random number, I believe that is the easiest part to add by yourself.

Comment: @Mas: This answer will work for you, you just need to change the part where he uses `n`, and instead change it to `10^n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a program for you:

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  cout << "Enter number: ";
  cin >> i;
  int m = 0;
  cout << "Enter divisor: ";
  cin >> m;
  if (m == 0)
  {
    cerr << "Can't divide by zero, aborting.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  cout << "Your number "
       << i;
  if ((i % m) == 0)
  {
    cout << " is divisible by " 
         << m
         << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "not divisible by " << m << "\n";
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You should be able to enter a 10 digit number and a divisor, m, and see the result.

Comment: =) its great answer. I hope he will understand it.

Comment: Man, i need to find ANY number with N digits divisible by a number!!

Comment: @mas That's probably more a simple math problem, than a programming question. What Thomas shows is easy to extrapolate to the number range you want, used in a loop. We're not providing you with ready made code here, or operate as an online debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities arising in the problem.
1. If M(<10) then the answer would be of type "MMMMMM...."upto N digits.
2. If M(==10) then if N==1 then there would be no number possible as no one digit would be divisible by 10 but for N>1 answer would be of type "11111.." upto N-1 digits followed by '0'.